# Search and get Records from Multiple Formate Date in php

Tags: php, date, mysqli, joomla, sql-like

I stored date in different formats like 29-06-1991, 29.06.1991, 29/06/1991 in my db Table. I need a search query to get all 29 june 1991 dated records.

```
$query = JFactory::getDbo()->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*');        
$query->from('#__orders');
$query->where('STR_TO_DATE(orderdateis,'%d-%m/%Y') ='.$db->Quote($rentaldate));
$db->setQuery($query);
```

Comment: what is the issue with current code?

Comment: @aMoLThite  i pass 29.06.1991 date via datepicker. no records are resulted

Comment: @Karthik have a solved your question? Are you having any trouble implementing it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with quotes try changing the below

> $query->where('STR_TO_DATE(orderdateis,'%d-%m/%Y') ='.$db->Quote($rentaldate));
>
> to
>
> $query->where("STR_TO_DATE(orderdateis,'%d-%m/%Y') =".$db->Quote($rentaldate));

Try to execute the query on MySQL console

You can use the following API to get the dump of query

> echo $query->dump(); jexit();

Comment: is the generated query giving you the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is only your delimiters that change (not the order of the number values), you can use `LIKE` very effectively with underscores to mark where any character will qualify.

Effectively, you prepare your php variable to suit the query.  ([Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3184c4/2))

```
$rentaldate = '29.06.1991';
$query->where("orderdateis LIKE " . $db->q(str_replace('.', '_', $rentaldate));
```

Or you can leave your variable unaltered and use the more expensive `REGEXP` call to leverage the "magic" of `.` which represents "any character": ([Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3184c4/3))

```
$rentaldate = '29.06.1991';
$query->where("orderdateis REGEXP " . $db->q($rentaldate))
```

I recommend the first.  I should also state that this could be done with more alternate techniques, but as I mentioned in your previous question, you should always store date values in date-type columns for easy of processing.

`STR_TO_DATE()` is a useful function, but poorly suited for your task because it requires you to specify the incoming date format so that it can properly read the string.  Unfortuntely, your date strings vary in format.